# The problem with "deleted x characters in body"

Tags: discussion, edits

My questions and answers (like everyone's) get edited a lot, and I notice that the edit explanations, which I feel are a very important part of the edit—especially to the OP—are often neglected. I try to learn from edits, and be grateful that it wasn't a downvote, but I often get this:

> Deleted [x] characters in body

Sometimes it is obvious what I did wrong, but other times not so much. Why require us to provide explanations if the explanations require explanations? That type of comment doesn't give any sort of reasoning, it doesn't explain what we did wrong, how can we learn from it?

This has happened to me a lot on Stack Overflow and Code Review.

Not sure if I would count this as a feature request, but you know how commenting checks to see if you are entering something like "lol" or "Thanks! me too!"? Could something like that be implemented for edits?

*If* I am wrong of course, and if there is a reason or something I am not seeing, could somebody please explain it to me in either the comments or an answer? I just don't see why it is harder to write "formatting" or something if you are editing formatting, or explaining why you are editing instead of using an explanation so generic it defeats the purpose of an edit explanation.

Comment: im gonna get crap for this aren't i

Comment: Just look at the diff.

Comment: @Mat sometime's its not that easy. its easy to tell what was removed or edited, but sometimes much harder to tell why

Comment: Can you show some examples of that?

Comment: This is what the system adds if the user doesn't enter a comment at all. We can't make people act sensibly unfortunately.

Comment: @RobertLongson just figured that out, am creating an answer now. thanks!

Comment: Something like the spam check system for comments. But instead of checking for spam, it would suggest that the user write something more descriptive.

Comment: If you really can't understand why the edit was made, you can ask the editor directly via a comment, e.g. "@John can you please explain your edit?" and even though the name won't appear in the autocomplete, the editor will get a notification and might post a reply.

Comment: I certainly sympathize with a dislike of the auto-generated edit summaries in most cases, and would agree it would be nice to reduce them, but I'm not sure getting rid of them entirely is a good idea. Sometimes, there really isn't much that needs to be said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The editors of your posts are people who volunteer their time to do so because they care about the quality of the Q&A on their Stack Exchange site(s).

Often they will have edited, answered and voted on many other questions that day.

Sometimes they will be able to find a little more time, and be keen, to explain their edits, but when they do not, I think users should simply think about why their question may have been edited the way it was, and if the reason is not obvious, and if a Meta search is not enlightening, then to ask on the Meta of the site performing any confusing edits as to why they may be happening.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have it figured out.

The OP, users with more than 2k reputation, and Moderators, are allowed to edit posts (either questions or answers) without leaving a comment. If they choose not to leave a comment, that is the default edit explanation—how many characters were added or removed.